# how to locate the template files of django-apps installed?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-rest-framework, django-apps

I am using Django Rest Framework in my project. I did `pip install djangorestFramework`.

Currently the template that is rendered is default ones that is shipped with `djangorestFramework`. I want to look into the template code so that I can override and customize to my needs.

It is specified in the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api) on how to override certain features/themes. But I want to change almost everything. so it would be great if I could have access to those templates to help build mine.

On a related note, how to find the templates directories of django-apps installed.

Comment: Did you check the [django rest framework's github repository](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/)?

Comment: @MattGiltaji: I want to locate it inside my project (since I have pip installed it)

Comment: are you using virtualenv?

Comment: yes I am using virtualenv. I cloned this project: https://github.com/tomchristie/rest-framework-tutorial. I don't see any template directory in there

Comment: It will be inside your virtual environment in a path like `env\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use [django-debug-toolbar](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.2/), you will have a template tab for every page where you can find all the used templates to build the page and for every template the absolute path is given.